# SOAP request in PHP with CURL

Tags: php, soap, curl

Since the SOAP manual on php.net is not very noob friendly and I could not find any good examples I will post my question here.

How can I create PHP SOAP request to look like this?

```
POST /MySERVER/myWSDLservice.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: connection.mywebsite.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://connection.mywebsite.com/MySERVER/GetCarType"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
  <GetCarType xmlns="http://connection.mywebsite.com/MySERVER/">
    <IDNumber>string</IDNumber>
  </GetCarType>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Please note:

- there is user/pass auth
- SSL connection

Any suggestion / links / example much appreciated.

Comment: [PHP::SOAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)

Comment: [The SoapClient class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)

Answer (score 177, accepted):

**Tested and working!**

- with https, user & password

  ```
   <?php 
   //Data, connection, auth
   $dataFromTheForm = $_POST['fieldName']; // request data from the form
   $soapUrl = "https://connecting.website.com/soap.asmx?op=DoSomething"; // asmx URL of WSDL
   $soapUser = "username";  //  username
   $soapPassword = "password"; // password

   // xml post structure

   $xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                       <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                         <soap:Body>
                           <GetItemPrice xmlns="http://connecting.website.com/WSDL_Service"> // xmlns value to be set to your WSDL URL
                             <PRICE>'.$dataFromTheForm.'</PRICE> 
                           </GetItemPrice >
                         </soap:Body>
                       </soap:Envelope>';   // data from the form, e.g. some ID number

      $headers = array(
                   "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                   "Accept: text/xml",
                   "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                   "Pragma: no-cache",
                   "SOAPAction: http://connecting.website.com/WSDL_Service/GetPrice", 
                   "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
               ); //SOAPAction: your op URL

       $url = $soapUrl;

       // PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword); // username and password - declared at the top of the doc
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

       // converting
       $response = curl_exec($ch); 
       curl_close($ch);

       // converting
       $response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
       $response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);

       // convertingc to XML
       $parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);
       // user $parser to get your data out of XML response and to display it. 
   ?>
  ```

Comment: The script works great and return XML SOAP response pastebin.com/9wzUV8Pw but I'm unable to parse the response into string, Any idea?

Comment: Without testing it the simplexml_load_string() cant handle the ":", right?

Comment: I'm trying to do consume a SOAP webservice using curl, but I only get an error that says "Unsupported Media Type". There is a way to force the Content-type header? When I set CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS the Content-type changes to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Comment: I found the problem here! I'm writing the headers using associative array. I only noted that when read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11091261/1128918

Comment: This, as of February 2017, still works as intended and helps people when they got headache while working with SOAP. I'd only like to point out the fact that, some servers, requires a prefix (like `<clin:price>`) for the xml tags (you can see that when the response contains a message about an unidentified sub-element)

Comment: This code sample works wonders, but if nstead of replacing the whole <soap:Body> like this str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response); you remove all the soap tags like this: str_replace("soap:", "", $response); It will also take care of the errors in the response, the "Fault", and it'll work for all types of responses.

Comment: @lladarsda can you please my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55980022/unable-to-convert-soap-response-string-to-xml-in-yii2) related to it ?

Comment: and if the script do not work: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); ` `0` in stead of `1` ignores problems with the SSL certificate. In my case it was the solution.

Comment: How to perform serialization to XML which is done by `\SoapClient` by default?