# soapclient, replace XML

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to trace rare, intermittent problem. A SOAP call is made, nice XML comes back, and information is stored in a database. On rare occasions though, some information goes missing. I cannot replicate this problem, but luckily the raw XML response is logged.

I have some nice debugging tracing functions on my development environment, so I would like to go through the process, but have the SoapClient use my xml, instead of what it receives from the server. I started to just replace `$result = $this->_mySoap->FUNC_NAME($params);` with `$result = // parse test.xml`

The problem is that the native SOAP function return an instance of SimpleClass, while parsing test.xml returns an instance of SimpleXMLElement class. I could try to convert one to the other, that would defeat my original goal of tracing the source of the intermittent bug in existing code.

Any thoughts on how I can force SoapClient to use this xml from a file, instead of actually making an api call?

Comment: SimpleClass? Do you mean [`stdClass`](http://php.net/reserved.classes)? And if you want to inject your XML, I think this is possible similar to when you use curl instead of standard HTTP wrappers from PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/de/soapclient.soapclient.php#97029; [SOAP request in PHP with CURL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7120586/367456)

Comment: Somehow I thought he wants the opposite - to simulate the XML that comes in response.

Comment: Currently, the only way I can think to do this, is to set up a fake server, change the URL for the request, and have it send back the XML I want to test. Replacing native SOAP with custom curl functions is simply not an option, as it defeats the whole point of debugging a single thing.