# Generating schema with soap PHP client

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

How can I generate this schema using php soap client cant seem to get a way

```css
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:loc="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/subscribe/manage/v1_0/local">
 <soapenv:Header>
 <tns:RequestSOAPHeader xmlns:tns="http://www.namesapace.com/common/v2_1">
 <tns:one>***</tns:one>
 <tns:two>***</tns:three>
 <oauth_token>***</oauth_token>
 </tns:RequestSOAPHeader>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
 <loc:ProductRequest>
 <subInfo>
 <productID>***</productID>
 <isAutoExtend>0</isAutoExtend>
 </subInfo>
 </loc:ProductRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please add what you've tried so far.

Comment: You don't need to handle XML stuff, just use the client object `new SoapClient()`

Answer (score 0):

On top of using the client, sometimes it may not bind to the namespace especially if using different soap versions or other strange reasons. Solved it by overriding the soap class and replacing the ns1 and ns2 values as described here http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php#74123

Answer (score 0):

IF no success with php soapclient, just post the request with curl.

Example in this answer - [SOAP request in PHP with CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120586/soap-request-in-php-with-curl)

Comment: awesome, can be another solution