# Send XML request to wsdl in php

Tags: php, xml, wsdl, soap-client

I have XML request format which I need to send to transunion api which is in wsdl. so how can I do it through PHP code?

This is the XML Request format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DCRequest xmlns="https://www.test.transuniondecisioncentre.co.in/DC/XYZ.Wrapper.ExternalService/XYZWrapperService.svc">
<Authentication type="OnDemand">
<UserId>Username</UserId>
<Password>Password</Password>
</Authentication>
<RequestInfo>
<SolutionSetId>884</SolutionSetId>
<SolutionSetVersion>24</SolutionSetVersion>
<ExecutionMode>NewWithContext</ExecutionMode>
</RequestInfo>
<UserData></UserData>
<Fields>
<Field key="EnvironmentType">U</Field>
<Field key="Title">sri</Field>
<Field key="FirstName">sdfsdfdsf</Field>
<Field key="MiddleName">AMEYA</Field>
<Field key="LastName">DAWARE</Field>
<Field key="DateOfBirth">23/09/1988</Field>
<Field key="Gender">MALE</Field>
<Field key="PanNo">BSLPD6648B</Field>
<Field key="EmailID">ruelosjoel@gmail.com</Field>
<Field key="ResidenceAddress1">B/404 BLDG NO.3 SHIV SHAKTI COMPLEX  ACH</Field>
<Field key="ResidenceAddress2">OLE RD NALLASOPARA EAST</Field>
<Field key="ResidenceAddress3"></Field>
<Field key="ResidencePincode">401203</Field>
<Field key="ResidenceCity">THANE</Field>
<Field key="ResidenceState">MAHARASHTRA</Field>
<Field key="ResidenceSTDCode"></Field>
<Field key="ResidencePhone"></Field>
</Fields>
</DCRequest>
```

Please help me.....

Comment: Use soap client => http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php

Comment: You don't need to create wsdl classes, you do in on the fly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120586/soap-request-in-php-with-curl

Answer (score -1):

Use [soapclient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php)

stackoverflow ref:
[How to make a PHP SOAP call using the SoapClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class)

Comment: "Send XML request to wsdl" is to send a custom request, PHP SOAP create the request