# How to add ConfigurationName in curl header for SOAP Request

Tags: php, api, curl, soap

I have working on the SOAP Request With CURL in PHP Password and Username over there but API is needed One Extra Filed of ConfigurationName, I have added this in Header but the Response is showing me an Error of

> FailedAuthentication

Following is my header code please check:

```
$headers=array(
"Content-type:text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
"Accept:text/xml",
"Cache-Control:no-cache",
"Pragma:no-cache",
"SOAPAction:\"actionurl\"",
"Content-length:".strlen($xml_post_string),
"ConfigurationName: ConfigurationName",
);

$url=$soapUrl;
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,$soapUser.":".$soapPassword);//usernameandpassword-declaredatthetopofthedoc
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,100);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$xml_post_string);//theSOAPrequest
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
```

Please assist me how to add this extra value of ConfigurationName in header.

Comment: Did you try sending it as post param ?

Comment: You means in $xml_post_string?

Comment: I would suggest you to use SoapClient : http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: yup ... but i guess *ConfigurationName* so i guess it wont work

Comment: In Postman it's working fine

Comment: so in postman are you sending your param as header or as post key ?

Comment: if it works in postman .. you can check your requested query in result .. check there how its format is. A Header request.

Comment: Like This: <soap:Header>
      <UserID></UserID>
      <Password></Password>
      <ConfigurationName></ConfigurationName>
  </soap:Header>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7157785/6829420

Comment: I would advice you to go for SoapClient as @Elbarto mentioned.

Comment: ok let me check thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139151/discussion-between-tarun-modi-and-mittul-at-technobrave).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fond the solution for this now I have set the ConfigurationName in xml like following and my script is working now:

```
$xml_post_string .='<soap:Header>';
$xml_post_string .='<UserID></UserID>';
$xml_post_string .='<Password></Password>';
$xml_post_string .='<ConfigurationName></ConfigurationName>';
$xml_post_string .='</soap:Header>';
```