# I'm trying to call a SOAP API request using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, api, soap

I am trying to call a soap api

I have the following request xml and wsdl addresses.

- test WSDL URL
  http://demo-activityws.touricoholidays.com/ActivityBookFlow.svc?wsdl
- sample request xml

how can i get response from API ???

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:aut="http://schemas.tourico.com/webservices/authentication" xmlns:act="http://tourico.com/webservices/activity" xmlns:act1="http://schemas.tourico.com/webservices/activity">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <aut:AuthenticationHeader>
         <aut:LoginName>John</aut:LoginName>
         <aut:Password>Johnpass</aut:Password>
         <aut:Culture>en_US</aut:Culture>
         <aut:Version>8</aut:Version>
      </aut:AuthenticationHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <act:SearchActivityByAirPortCode>
         <act:SearchRequest destination="MCO" cityName="Orlando">
            <act1:FromDate>2017-03-23</act1:FromDate>
            <act1:ToDate>2017-03-25</act1:ToDate>
            <act1:Filters>
               <act1:MinAdults>
                  <act1:Value>0</act1:Value>
               </act1:MinAdults>
               <act1:MinChildren>
                  <act1:Value>0</act1:Value>
               </act1:MinChildren>
               <act1:MinUnits>
                  <act1:Value>0</act1:Value>
               </act1:MinUnits>
               <act1:CategoryName>
                  <act1:Value>Theme Parks</act1:Value>
               </act1:CategoryName>
               <act1:CategoryId>
                  <act1:Value>592</act1:Value>
               </act1:CategoryId>
               <act1:ActivityName>
                  <act1:Value>SeaWorld Orlando</act1:Value>
               </act1:ActivityName>
            </act1:Filters>
         </act:SearchRequest>
      </act:SearchActivityByAirPortCode>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120586/soap-request-in-php-with-curl this would help

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class#answer-11714489